# How to pass data from applet to web page client code?

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

How to pass data (like string) from applet to web page client code? that is to value parameter of a label (or asp label).
Is it possible to change the value of  (member of  tag) from applet?

Is it possible to do it without javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: What is *web page client code*? Do you want to change the HTML code of the page in which the applet is? Or do you have other scripts running in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

As I can remember, you can use the netscape lib for this. watch [this example](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch22_02.htm) [and this one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) as a conception demo...
the lib helps to make Java applet and JavaScript interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use RHINO(API by mozilla) to send the data to JS and then send it.

or (never tried this 1 though) create an intermediate class with a static member variable assign the data to it. and use it at server side.